# Unix File Merge - If key exists replace line with value

Tags: unix, ksh

I have 2 files table.cols and table.rules

table.cols:

```
column_1
column_2
column_3
column_4
column_5
```

table.rules:

```
column_3 my_function(column_3, another_parameter)
column_4 my_other_function(column_3, a_different_parameter)
```

I want to merge these files to produce:

```
column_1,
column_2,
my_function(column_3, another_parameter),
my_other_function(column_3, a_different_parameter),
column_5
```

Notice the commas at the end of each line except the last.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
  $ head file?
==> file1 <==
column_3 my_function(column_3, another_parameter)
column_4 my_other_function(column_3, a_different_parameter)

==> file2 <==
column_1
column_2
column_3
column_4
column_5
$ awk -v line=$(wc -l < file2) 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2FS$3;next} {print (a[$1] ?a[$1]OFS :((FNR<line)?$0 OFS:$0))}'  OFS=, file1 file2
column_1,
column_2,
my_function(column_3, another_parameter),
my_other_function(column_3, a_different_parameter),
column_5
```

Explained :

```
((FNR<line)?$0 OFS:$0)) : to ignore the comma from last line.
```

Answer (score 0):

This script works as expected:

```
#! /bin/sh

OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
NL=$(cat table.cols| wc -l)
CL=1

rm -f /tmp/tablecols /tmp/tablerules

for LINE in $(cat table.cols)
do
    echo -ne "${LINE}" >> /tmp/tablecols
    if [ $CL -lt $NL ]; then
        echo "," >> /tmp/tablecols
        CL=$((CL + 1))
    else
        echo "" >> /tmp/tablecols
    fi
done

for LINE in $(cat table.rules)
do
    KEY=$(echo $LINE|cut -f 1 -d " ")
    VAL=$(echo $LINE| cut -f 2-5 -d " ")
    sed -i "s/${KEY}/${VAL}/g" /tmp/tablecols
done
mv /tmp/tablecols result
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
join -a1 table.cols table.rules | sed -e 1,4s/$/,/
```

- join to combine the files
- -a FILENUM        print unpairable lines
- sed commands have an optional range
- substitute end-of-line with `,`